# How do you use the sample codes while reading programming books?

Tags: learning

Programming books often contain a lot of code scattered within it. Usually there will be an accompanying website to download the code used in the book.

How do you use the code? Do you just run them and check the results or do you code it from scratch again?

If you are coding it from scratch, have you found any advantages( like remembering the content better etc)?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20455/is-it-wrong-to-use-the-word-codes-in-a-programming-context

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best advice on the matter I know of comes from the prologue of Zed Shaw's [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/):

> This simple book is meant to get you
>   started in programming. The title says
>   it’s the hard way to learn to write
>   code; but it’s actually not. It’s only
>   the “hard” way because it’s the way
>   people used to teach things. With the
>   help of this book, you will do the
>   incredibly simple things that all
>   programmers need to do to learn a
>   language:
>
> 1. Go through each exercise.
> 2. Type in each sample exactly.
> 3. Make it run.
>
> That’s it. This will be very difﬁcult
>   at ﬁrst, but stick with it.

And later on he elaborates:

> It seems stupidly obvious, but, if you
>   have a problem typing, you will have a
>   problem learning to code. Especially
>   if you have a problem typing the
>   fairly odd characters in source code.
>   Without this simple skill you will be
>   unable to learn even the most basic
>   things about how software works.
>
> Typing the code samples and getting
>   them to run will help you learn the
>   names of the symbols, get familiar
>   with typing them, and get you reading
>   the language.

Almost all of the prologue is dedicated to why typing code is preferred, there is no point to copy it here, there's a free pdf version of the book you can read.

So, to answer your question, I always type in the code. Every time you choose to type the code instead of just compiling / running the accompanying code you actually get some valuable practice and extra [muscle memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle_memory) points in the language's syntax, conventions and quirks. It's not just the code that matters, unless all you want to achieve is reading the language.

Python, where indentation is a [language requirement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29#Indentation) and not a matter of style, is a perfect example of why you need to type everything when learning.